# Adding case statement inside where condition and provide conditional statements inside then clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I have a `where` clause in which i need to add `case` statement and inside `then` and `else`  i have to give conditional statement.

My where condition looks like this

```
WHERE 
    CASE
        WHEN 
        Substring(datename(dw,getdate()),1,3) = 'mon' 
        THEN convert(varchar,dt_start,103) = convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-3,getdate()),103) 
        AND  convert(varchar,dt_start,103) <= convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-2,getdate()),103)
        ELSE convert(varchar,dt_start,103) = convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-1,getdate()),103)
    END
```

But this query is showing syntax error at `=` inside `then`. The same logic works in PostgreSQL but when i tried in SQL server it has got syntax error at =. How i can solve this. Please help
 This is the corresponding PGSQL query.

```
WHERE 
    CASE
        WHEN to_char(now(), 'dy'::text) = 'mon'::text THEN to_char(dt_start, 'yyyymmdd'::text) = to_char(now() - '3 days'::interval, 'yyyymmdd'::text) AND to_char(dt_start, 'yyyymmdd'::text) <= to_char(now() - '2 days'::interval, 'yyyymmdd'::text)
        ELSE to_char(dt_start, 'yyyymmdd'::text) = to_char(now() - '1 day'::interval, 'yyyymmdd'::text)
    END
```

Comment: I fail to see how this could possibly work in PostgreSQL or in any other RDBMS. `CASE` in SQL is an *expression* that returns a single scalar value. It cannot be used to control execution flow like in procedural languages.

Comment: Yes it is working in pgsql. i have added the pgsql where clause in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: You have to make two separate conditions based on your requirement and remember onething, you can only start `CASE` as `WHERE a = CASE` not as `WHERE CASE ...THEN a = b+c ...`
or in such cases I would suggest to go with dynamic queries where it's quite easy to manipulate the queries based on the different conditions

```
WHERE convert(varchar,dt_start,103) =
    CASE WHEN Substring(datename(dw,getdate()),1,3) = 'mon' THEN 
        convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-3,getdate()),103) 
    ELSE 
        convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-1,getdate()),103) 
    END

    AND convert(varchar,dt_start,103) <= 
    CASE WHEN Substring(datename(dw,getdate()),1,3) = 'mon' THEN
        convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-2,getdate()),103)
    ELSE 
        convert(varchar,dt_start,103)
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

- try this

  ```
  WHERE 
  convert(varchar,dt_start,103)=
  CASE
      WHEN 
      Substring(datename(dw,getdate()),1,3) = 'mon' 
      THEN convert(varchar,dt_start,103) = 
      convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-3,getdate()),103) 
      ELSE convert(varchar,dt_start,103) = 
      convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-1,getdate()),103)
  END  

  AND

  convert(varchar,dt_start,103)<=
  CASE
   WHEN 
   Substring(datename(dw,getdate()),1,3) = 'mon' 
    then convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-2,getdate()),103)
    else
    --put a condition that does not filter any data (maybe)
    convert(varchar,getdate(),103)
    end
  ```

Comment: Thanking you for your answer.