# How can I change Where statement based on parameter value - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm receiving parameter status value as integer, 1, 2, 3 etc and that is fine,
but since one status from parameters represents 2 values in database for example when I receive 2 as a status I need to compare if status=2 and status=5 that means I should expand my Where statement so here is my query:

```
...rest of the query

WHERE products.company_id = $1 AND products.status = ANY ($10)
                               AND (products_files.check_date BETWEEN $2 AND $3)
                               AND ($6 IS NULL OR products.supplier_company_id = $6)  
                               AND ($7 IS NULL OR products.payment_method = $7) 
                               AND ($8 IS NULL OR products.status = $8)
```

Now I would like to do something like "If products.status = 2 than lets check for two of the statuses 
instead of `AND ($8 IS NULL OR products.status = $8)` I would like to check something like

```
AND ($8 IS NULL OR products.status = 2 And product.status = 5)
```

Since I'm really beginner at sql I can't figure this out..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding case statement inside where condition and provide conditional statements inside then clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940077/adding-case-statement-inside-where-condition-and-provide-conditional-statements)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Postgres